# Anchor tag Onserverclick event

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2007

Trying to implement server side click to anchor tag
Below code is in .CS file(sharepoint 2007/c#)

```
lblDetails.Text += userCreds[i].UserInfoID + " - " + "[a href='#' runat ='server' onserverclick='LinkButton_Click ]+ userCreds[i].AccountName + "[/a] ";

public void LinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{}
```

when cliking on link it is not going to LinkButton_clicked menthod

Please help !!!

Comment: Does your code actually compile? Looks like you're missing a `"` after `'LinkButton_Click ]`.

Actually, you're also missing a `'`. So it should be `onserverclick='LinkButton_Click' ]" + `...etc.

I don't know Sharepoint, so I don't know if the code is otherwise valid, but that looks like a definite issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works:

- Add a button that will do the action normally eg btnLinkButton
- Register the event handler:

  `btnLinkButton.Click += new EventHandler(LinkButton_Click);`
- Add an event to the label

`lblDetails.Attributes.Add("onclick", ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnLinkButton, null))`

Answer (score 0):

Try hooking up the event with a delegate/event handler like below instead of injecting it with the `onserverclick` tag.

```
lblDetails.Click += new EventHandler(LinkButton_Click);
```

Comment: I see.  Well then consider manually posting back with some custom js  by injecting onclick="jsMethod()" and function jsMethod() { document.forms[0].submit(); }